# getting the error: Error in c[4:16] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the summary statistics using the data.frame() function for my csv file. I only want to have the quantitative columns so I have been using ...df[,c[4:16]] which are the quantitative columns. But, I am getting the error: Error in c[4:16] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable. I am not quite sure how to fix my code so that it returns the summary statistics with just those columns.
Code:

```
cereals.df <- read.csv("Cereals.csv", header=TRUE) #load data 
#using the data.frame() function
data.frame(mean=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],mean,na.rm=TRUE),
           sd=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],sd,na.rm=TRUE),
           min=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],min,na.rm=TRUE),
           max=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],max,na.rm=TRUE),
           median=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],median,na.rm=TRUE),
           length=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],length),
           miss.val=sapply(cereals.df[,c[4:16]],function(x)
             sum(length(which(is.na(x))))))
```

Comment: Hi there user 13383426. Welcome to SO. Perhaps you mixed `c[4:16]` with `c(4:16)` or simply `4:16`?

Comment: Thanks! I think I actually figured it out. I just created a new variable that just has those columns and then inserted that new variable in place of the cereals.df...

Comment: library(tidyverse)
quantitative <- cereals.df %>% select(4:16)
data.frame(mean=sapply(quantitative,mean,na.rm=TRUE),
           sd=sapply(quantitative,sd,na.rm=TRUE),
           min=sapply(quantitative,min,na.rm=TRUE),
           max=sapply(quantitative,max,na.rm=TRUE),
           median=sapply(quantitative,median,na.rm=TRUE),
           length=sapply(quantitative,length),
           miss.val=sapply(quantitative,function(x)
             sum(length(which(is.na(x))))))